# Zend Framework Redirector Helper Routes

Tags: php, redirect, zend-framework, routes

so I have this problem for two days that I can't figure out till now. Basically I created a simple login according to [this](https://akrabat.com/zend-auth-tutorial/) Rob Allen's tutorial and some to adjust it with my environment. In that tutorial, when a user authenticated the login page redirected to Zend index page. Now I want to redirect it in success.phtml page, located in views/scripts/auth. Here's the code :

```
public function indexAction() {
    $form = new Application_Form_Login();
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request->isPost()) {
        if ($form->isValid($request->getPost())) {
            if ($this->_process($form->getValues())) {
                // We're authenticated! Redirect to the home page
                $this->_helper->redirector('success', 'auth');
            }
        }
    }
    $this->view->form = $form;
}

public function successAction(){
    $this->_redirector->gotoUrl('/auth/success');
    return;
}
```

Before I add successAction function, the page shows error because there is no said function created. But now, it shows page not found that resulted in too many redirects. How exactly the Zend's redirect works? Any help appreciated.

Comment: I got the answer, just empty successAction method...